# How to mock case class?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I have following case class:

```
case class User(username:String, createdDate:DateTime)
```

and a class to test:

```
class UserDAO{
def registerUser(user:User)
}
```

I want to verify that `registerUser` called with an input user that has `username="myusername"`. Based on this docs https://mockito.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.7/javadoc/org/mockito/Matchers.html I came up with a code like this:

```
verify(userDAO).registerUser(User(eq("myusername"),any[DateTime]))
```

however it is not right and I had error while compiling.

Error is `Type mismatch, expected UUID actual Boolean`

Comment: When you get an error, never just say "I had an error". Copy and paste the exact error message. Error messages contain important information about what the problem is.

Comment: You're not trying to mock a case class there. You're constructing the class and trying to give it hamcrest matchers as arguments. Nor do I think mocking `User` is what you even want to do here... don't you just want to create a matcher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using a different approach. I used `capture` the input argument of a mocked object and then validate the captured value.

http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html